# ESP8266 spend 10mA, even though It is in the deep sleep mode

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, sleep

I am using Nodemcu ESP8266. I want to know how much my ESP board consume the battery during sleep mode.
as the Mannual said it spend about micro-ampere, but my multi meter said it spend 10 mili-ampere, I cannot believe the result.

so please see My arrangement is right and give some advice

[arrangement image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTVLQ.jpg)

[image]

red line is for vin, black line is for GND.
black pin is COM, red pin is mA.

I set multimeter on 20mA, 200mA, it said it is 10mA.
when I change multimeter to 10mA, 1mA, microAmpere, number was overflowed.

I already connected to RST - D0, so It is properly sleep & wake up automatically. and here is my running code in the board

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h> 
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>

void setup() {

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:


ESP.deepSleep(60e6);

}
```

Comment: You seem to be measuring the consumption of the _whole board_, not just the ESP8266.

Comment: O really? then I should optimize board also? but is it possible?

Comment: Usually, those breakout boards use CH340 Serial-USB converter. If USB is not connected, it automatically goes in deepsleep mode, It shouldn't consume more that 50uA. It can't be the problem, however, if you are skilled enough, you can desolder it to test its the power consumption.

Comment: There are other ESP8266 dev boards that consume less power while in deep sleep. Looks like you have a NodeMCU. Try a few other dev boards (e.g. I found that the LOLIN D1 mini consumes about 100 uA or 0.1 mA while in deep sleep). I also found that over time, components on the dev boards can become damaged (e.g. the voltage regulator) due to abuse, so that's also something to watch for.

Answer (score 1):

`ESP.deepSleep(60e6, WAKE_RF_DEFAULT);` Try this code, it should decrease it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The Board you are using contains an ESP-12F Module, along with other chips that make it easy/possible to connect to UART over USB and thus flash the chip. This USB-to-UART converter chip isn't related to the ESP-12F Module, so is unaffected when the ESP goes to sleep, so the converter continues to draw about 10mA. You can't do anything about this unless you desolder it, or use a pure ESP-12F Module.